# FFmpeg read from file which is dynamically grows

Tags: ffmpeg

When i try to to read media packets with

```
while(true)
{     
     av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);

}
```

av_read_frame return **EOF** after a little time although the file is still grows.

How can i force ffmpeg to read file continously?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 1):

Use the pipe: protocol handler instead of a file pointer.